# Finding Twin primes Such That Their Sum + 1 is Also Prime

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Let p and p+2 be Two Prime Numbers.

*What Is The Necessary Condition For P such that:*

$(P + (P + 2)) + 1 $  *is also prime???*

By inspection , I found that (5,7),(17,19) satisfies the above condition but what is a general solution for this?

Comment: You can use the PNT to determine an asymptotic density for such clusters. This will very likely be similar to the density of prime 3-tuples

Comment: We are looking for triples of primes $(p,p+2,2p+3)$. There is no "the necessary condition" for finding them, so no "general solution". There is also no general solution for numbers $p$ to be prime. We know that it starts with $p=2,3,5,7,..$ but there is no  explicit "formula for the general solution".

Comment: $p+1$ can't be of form $2ab+a+b$ for $a,b\in\Bbb{N}$ @Dietrich

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: sieve of sundaram and arithmetic mean. it's more of a necessary condition, not the only one... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency

Comment: @Peter Yes,alongside the reason..

Comment: @Peter How And Why ??

Comment: The $50$ primes upto $10^4$ with the desired property (calculated with pari/gp) : ? forprime(p=1,10^4,if(ispseudoprime(p+2)==1,if(ispseudoprime(2*p+3)==1,print1(p
," "))))
5 17 29 137 197 227 269 599 617 659 809 827 1277 1427 1607 2027 2087 2129 2309 2
549 2789 3167 3329 3389 3527 3767 4049 4157 4229 4259 4337 4637 4799 5417 5477 5
657 5849 6269 6299 6359 6689 6959 7559 7949 8537 8627 9239 9719 9857 9929
?

Comment: @Peter $p$ can't be of form $2ab+a+b-1$

Comment: The ending digit of $p$ must be $7$ or $9$ (except the case $p=5$)

Comment: @Peter that's all the OP asked for they don't know about sufficiency.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee OK, I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit There are several necessary conditions. Which kind of conditions you are looking for ?

Comment: they technically say The so I guess I see your point. however a necessary condition is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98848/discussion-between-peter-and-roddy-macphee).